# Input validation using cin object and also clearing buffer(c++)

Tags: c++, buffer, inputstream, cout, cin

Previously I'm a C programmer(wanna know more about system programming but don't wanna go into assembly so i choose C) more  but later on in my University I have to take C++ , I'm actually having a hard time on using the `cin` and `cout` object as it has some changes compare to my trusted `printf()` , `scanf()` , `getchar()` macro in C . Here's the code.

**The Code**

```
 int main(void)
 {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "What is the number?\n\n";
    cout << "#Number :";
    cin >> num;

    while(cin.fail())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(1000 , '\n');
        cout << "Please enter a number\n\n";
        cout << "#Number :";
        cin >> num;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

**The Question**

1.)I want this code to ask for a number from user ( less than and more than or equal to 0) , when user enter a character or string , i want it to alert user about it , clear the input buffer and reprompt user for a new value until it's a number.

2.)So i just googling around and find a page preaching the method , so i just follow the way but it failed . I've no idea why once i run this code , type in a character it will causes infinite looping of the output `Please enter a number`.Any mistake done by me in this code??

*Thanks for spending time reading my problem*

P/S : I'm using CodeBlocks with minGW compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how it failed, so it's difficult to say what your problem
is.  The fact that you never declare `num` is one obvious problem.  And
it will fail if you enter a line longer than 1000 characters as well.

A more idiomatic solution in C++ would be to read the input line by line, using `std::getline`, and then using `std::istringstream` to convert the line into a number.

Comment: Ok thanks , anyway in original source code i do declare it :) just in here i forgot to add in the line

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to use formatting input is inside a conditional check on the operation itself. Also, you'll want to read an entire line and attempt to parse that rather than extract token by token. E.g. like this:

```
int num;

for (bool success = false; !success; )
{
  std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";

  std::string line;
  if (std::cin >> line)
  {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> num) success = true;
  }

  if (!success) { std::cout << "Error!\n"; }
}

std::cout << "Thank you. You said: " << num << std::endl;
```

Feel free to add further diagnostic output in the error branch.